# Наполнение массива из метода

Tags: java

Друзья, столкнулся с проблемой:

1. В классе создан массив
2. Есть метод, который выбирает случайное слово и дробит его на буквы.

Нужно сделать так, что бы массив становился равным слову сгенерированным в методе каждый раз при вызове GenerateWord(). Я перепробовал все что угодно, но сделать так не выходит от слова совсем.

```
String[] GenerateWord(){
        String[] wordList = {"яблоко","бардак","грабли"};
        int oneLength = wordList.length;
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        String RandomWord = wordList[rand1];
        String[] RWordom = RandomWord.split("");//разбив по буквам
        return RWordom;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то так

```
class YouClass{

     String[] arr;

     void GenerateWord(){
          String[] wordList = {"яблоко","бардак","грабли"};
          int oneLength = wordList.length;
          int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
          String RandomWord = wordList[rand1];
          this.arr = RandomWord.split("");//разбив по буквам
     }
}
```

Comment: Так то работает, спасибо! Но вот дальше с этим массивом как работать я не понимаю. Вывести на печать, передать, как аргумент - без проблем. Но передать в другой массив или скопировать- не выходит.

Comment: Спасибо здесь принято говорить принятием ответа галочкой слева от ответа и стрелками голосования если вам ответ помог

Comment: Что касается операций с массивами - можете использовать класс Arrays там есть утилитные методы. А если вручную - создаете новый массив, делаете обход циклом по элементам старого массива и новому массиву присваиваете значения.